# How to convert "frozenset({})" string to the data type frozenset?

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

I am trying to learn recommendation systems. I've imported associative rules to my sheet but antecedents and consequents values are formatted as strings I need to convert them to the data type frozenset in python.
If a have a string like `"frozenset({3048, 3046})"` I need to convert it to `(3048,3046)`
How can I do that?

Here is the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd

frozen_df =  [{"antecedents" : "frozenset({3048, 3046})","consequents" : "frozenset({10})"},
              {"antecedents" : "frozenset({3504, 3507})","consequents" : "frozenset({3048, 85})"}]

frozen_df = pd.DataFrame(frozen_df)
frozen_df.dtypes
```

Comment: Better to fix whatever is creating these strings in the first place.  Creating dicts like this just causes problems.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thank you I'll consider this. I keep learning every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure can split them up, e.g. using

```
def to_frozenset(x):
    return frozenset(map(int, x.split("{")[1].split("}")[0].split(",")))

frozen_df = frozen_df.applymap(to_frozenset)
```

Note, however, that `frozen_df.dtypes` will still be `object`, since there is not "frozenset dtype" in Pandas. Instead, looking at a single element (`frozen_df.iloc[0, 0]`) will demonstrate that the elements are indeed frozensets.

Comment: @FikriÇetin As a side note I do agree with snakecharmerb's comment that you should fix this problem upstream by making sure that the data come in as numeric values, not as string representations of data types.